# SoapUI generates JSON property for namespace

Tags: json, jax-rs, cxf, soapui, wadl

I generate a WADL with CXF as described in [CXF – Missing WADL method parameter element types with JSON JAX-RS services](http://www.devsumo.com/technotes/2015/01/cxf-missing-wadl-method-parameter-element-types-with-json-jax-rs-services/).

I tried to generate the JSON request body in SoapUI ("Recreates a default representation from the schema"), but I get the wrong JSON including namespace.

**Code:**

CXF configuration:

```xml
<bean id="wadlGenerator" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
    <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
</bean>

<jaxrs:server address="/rest/1" id="test" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="testResource" /> 
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
        <ref bean="wadlGenerator" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**WADL:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<application xmlns:prefix1="http://www.test.com/test" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <grammars>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com/test" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:import/>
            <xs:element name="testModel" type="testModel"/>
        </xs:schema>
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.test.com/test" targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/test" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
            <xs:complexType name="testModel">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </grammars>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/test-app/services/rest/1">
        <resource path="/test">
            <method name="POST">
                <request>
                    <representation mediaType="application/json" element="prefix1:testModel"/>
                </request>
                <response status="204"/>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

**JSON:**

```
{
   "@xmlns:test": "http://www.test.com/test",
   "id": "?",
   "name": "?"
}
```

Is that a bug/missing feature of SoapUI or is there something wrong with my WADL?